# Convert special character (âˆš) into normal string using bash

Tags: bash, hex

I would like to convert following hex string into normal string and replace inline in file content. âˆš hex character is for checkbox TRUE sign.

[image]

## Input file:

Create Contact List
    âˆš L0 | Create contact list | C432965 (2466ms)

Create Contact
    1) L0 | Create basic contact | C679288

## Expected file:

Create Contact List
    REPLACED L0 | Create contact list | C432965 (2466ms)

Create Contact
    1) L0 | Create basic contact | C679288

## Hexdump of sample file:

```
root@server:/portal# hexdump -C /report.txt

00000000  0a 0a 20 20 43 72 65 61  74 65 20 43 6f 6e 74 61  |..  Create Conta|
00000010  63 74 20 4c 69 73 74 0a  20 20 20 20 e2 88 9a 20  |ct List.    ... |
00000020  4c 30 20 7c 20 43 72 65  61 74 65 20 63 6f 6e 74  |L0 | Create cont|
00000030  61 63 74 20 6c 69 73 74  20 7c 20 43 34 33 32 39  |act list | C4329|
00000040  36 35 20 28 32 34 36 36  6d 73 29 0a 0a 20 20 43  |65 (2466ms)..  C|
00000050  72 65 61 74 65 20 43 6f  6e 74 61 63 74 0a 20 20  |reate Contact.  |
00000060  20 20 31 29 20 4c 30 20  7c 20 43 72 65 61 74 65  |  1) L0 | Create|
00000070  20 62 61 73 69 63 20 63  6f 6e 74 61 63 74 20 7c  | basic contact ||
00000080  20 43 36 37 39 32 38 38  0a 0a                    | C679288..|
0000008a
```

## Tried code:

I can convert this hex string with iconv and tr in variable but how can i achieve same to replace entire file it retries such content?

```
echo "âˆš" | iconv -f UTF-8 | tr 'âˆš' 'REPLACED' | ed -s /report.txt

sed -i 's/âˆš/REPLACED/g' /report.txt

perl -pi -e 's/âˆš/REPLACED/g' /report.txt
```

Is there any solution through sed -i -e to modify file directly for such special character?

Comment: I had tried this, meanwhile added in tried code too. Thanks!

Comment: Add output of `hexdump -C input_file` to your question.

Comment: Added hexdump content of file.

Comment: Your input file and output of hexdump do not match. The hexdump contains strings like `Create basic contact` which are not part of the Input file you showed us. Also, could you please use a regular hexdump, using `xxd file` or `hexdump -C file` (note the **captial** C)?

Comment: It was sample file because i was not wanted to send unrequired characters. Anyhow, i just made cut to cut with input and expected with partial file content. Please accept the question.

Comment: Can anyone reply if you know solution after getting hexdump?

Comment: Follow Socowi's comment.

Comment: Kindly check updated hexdump in the description now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e2 88 9a` is the important part of your hexdump.

With GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/\xe2\x88\x9a/REPLACED/' /report.txt
```